# Appcelerator Titanium JS dosen't parse Date() as expected

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am using Appcelerator Titanium, and I'm trying to parse a date string as a new Date object and then use the `.getTime()` function but it keeps returning "NaN"

```
var d = new Date("2014-02-01T00:00:00");
var time = d.getTime();
console.log(time); // returns NaN
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? It works when I create a new date for now, like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getTime();
console.log(time); // returns correct value
```

I can't see why the first example is working but the second example is not.

Comment: It doesn't appear that Date supports that functionality.  Titanium uses JavaScript for the business logic and I can't find anything confirming that Date supports the way you are using it.  It looks like there are attempts out there to try converting XML date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178598/xml-datetime-to-javascript-date-object, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731579/convert-an-xml-schema-date-string-to-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to parse a UTC date time. In Titanium, when you try to parse the date, it will return invalid date. So you need to convert it to datetime string. You can use [Convert UTC Date to datetime string Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380046/convert-utc-date-to-datetime-string-titanium) to convert the time.