# Strangly couldn't compare between two integers in titanium

Tags: javascript, date, titanium

after resolving [my problem about converting a string into a date in titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826161/invalid-date-for-a-new-dateyyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-instanciation?noredirect=1#comment33035434_21826161) , i managed to get that date in milliseconds and the current time too as shown in this code :

```
    Ti.API.error("+*///+++ FormatDate(NightsArray[i][3]).getTime() : "+parseInt(FormatDate(NightsArray[i][3]).getTime()));
    var date1 = parseInt(FormatDate(NightsArray[i][3]).getTime());

    Ti.API.error("+*///+++ d.getTime() : "+parseInt(d.getTime()));
    var date2 = parseInt(d.getTime());

    Ti.API.error("+*///+++ comparaison : "+date2 < date1);
    Ti.API.error("+*///+++ comparaison : "+date2 > date1);

    if(date2 > date1)
        Ti.API.error("+*///+++ Diff : "+date2 - date1);
    else    
        Ti.API.error("+*///+++ Diff : "+date1 - date2);
```

i parsed these both dates formatted in milliseconds into integers hopping finally to get rid of dates problems by only working with numbers but as shown in the console : all comparaisons return 0 and the difference NaN

```
[ERROR] :  +*///+++FormatDate(date) : Thu Feb 20 2014 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
[ERROR] :  +*///+++ FormatDate(NightsArray[i][3]).getTime() : 1392933600000
[ERROR] :  +*///+++ d.getTime() : 1392634864589
[ERROR] :  0
[ERROR] :  0
[ERROR] :  NaN
```

What's wrong !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple mistake in your code. Your code will not work unless you put the expressions in parentheses.

Try changing the code as follows

```
Ti.API.info("comparisson-1 : " + (date2 < date1));
Ti.API.error("comparisson-2 : " + (date2 > date1));

if(date2 > date1)
    Ti.API.info("Difference-1 " + (date2 - date1));
else    
    Ti.API.error("Difference-2 " + (date1 - date2));
```

Check the above code and let me know the progress