# xml2json - "X2JS is not defined"

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I'm using xml2json for the first time to get an review feed to populate on a website and I keep getting errors such as;

> Uncaught ReferenceError: X2JS is not defined

and

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'X2JS' of undefined

I can't seem to find a solution, this is the code;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//below here

//API Feed for Testimonials

(function (root, factory) {
     if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
         define([], factory);
     } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
         module.exports = factory();
     } else {
         root.X2JS = factory();
     }
 }(this, function () {
    return function (config) {
        'use strict';

        var VERSION = "1.2.0";

        config = config || {};
        initConfigDefaults();
        initRequiredPolyfills();

        function initConfigDefaults() {
            if(config.escapeMode === undefined) {
                config.escapeMode = true;
            }

            config.attributePrefix = config.attributePrefix || "_";
            config.arrayAccessForm = config.arrayAccessForm || "none";
            config.emptyNodeForm = config.emptyNodeForm || "text";      

            if(config.enableToStringFunc === undefined) {
                config.enableToStringFunc = true; 
            }
            config.arrayAccessFormPaths = config.arrayAccessFormPaths || []; 
            if(config.skipEmptyTextNodesForObj === undefined) {
                config.skipEmptyTextNodesForObj = true;
            }
            if(config.stripWhitespaces === undefined) {
                config.stripWhitespaces = true;
            }
            config.datetimeAccessFormPaths = config.datetimeAccessFormPaths || [];

            if(config.useDoubleQuotes === undefined) {
                config.useDoubleQuotes = false;
            }

            config.xmlElementsFilter = config.xmlElementsFilter || [];
            config.jsonPropertiesFilter = config.jsonPropertiesFilter || [];

            if(config.keepCData === undefined) {
                config.keepCData = false;
            }
        }

        var DOMNodeTypes = {
            ELEMENT_NODE       : 1,
            TEXT_NODE          : 3,
            CDATA_SECTION_NODE : 4,
            COMMENT_NODE       : 8,
            DOCUMENT_NODE      : 9
        };

        function initRequiredPolyfills() {      
        }

        function getNodeLocalName( node ) {
            var nodeLocalName = node.localName;         
            if(nodeLocalName == null) // Yeah, this is IE!! 
                nodeLocalName = node.baseName;
            if(nodeLocalName == null || nodeLocalName=="") // =="" is IE too
                nodeLocalName = node.nodeName;
            return nodeLocalName;
        }

        function getNodePrefix(node) {
            return node.prefix;
        }

        function escapeXmlChars(str) {
            if(typeof(str) == "string")
                return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
            else
                return str;
        }

        function unescapeXmlChars(str) {
            return str.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
        }

        function checkInStdFiltersArrayForm(stdFiltersArrayForm, obj, name, path) {
            var idx = 0;
            for(; idx < stdFiltersArrayForm.length; idx++) {
                var filterPath = stdFiltersArrayForm[idx];
                if( typeof filterPath === "string" ) {
                    if(filterPath == path)
                        break;
                }
                else
                if( filterPath instanceof RegExp) {
                    if(filterPath.test(path))
                        break;
                }               
                else
                if( typeof filterPath === "function") {
                    if(filterPath(obj, name, path))
                        break;
                }
            }
            return idx!=stdFiltersArrayForm.length;
        }

        function toArrayAccessForm(obj, childName, path) {
            switch(config.arrayAccessForm) {
                case "property":
                    if(!(obj[childName] instanceof Array))
                        obj[childName+"_asArray"] = [obj[childName]];
                    else
                        obj[childName+"_asArray"] = obj[childName];
                    break;
                /*case "none":
                    break;*/
            }

            if(!(obj[childName] instanceof Array) && config.arrayAccessFormPaths.length > 0) {
                if(checkInStdFiltersArrayForm(config.arrayAccessFormPaths, obj, childName, path)) {
                    obj[childName] = [obj[childName]];
                }           
            }
        }

        function fromXmlDateTime(prop) {
            // Implementation based up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178598/xml-datetime-to-javascript-date-object
            // Improved to support full spec and optional parts
            var bits = prop.split(/[-T:+Z]/g);

            var d = new Date(bits[0], bits[1]-1, bits[2]);          
            var secondBits = bits[5].split("\.");
            d.setHours(bits[3], bits[4], secondBits[0]);
            if(secondBits.length>1)
                d.setMilliseconds(secondBits[1]);

            // Get supplied time zone offset in minutes
            if(bits[6] && bits[7]) {
                var offsetMinutes = bits[6] * 60 + Number(bits[7]);
                var sign = /\d\d-\d\d:\d\d$/.test(prop)? '-' : '+';

                // Apply the sign
                offsetMinutes = 0 + (sign == '-'? -1 * offsetMinutes : offsetMinutes);

                // Apply offset and local timezone
                d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - offsetMinutes - d.getTimezoneOffset())
            }
            else
                if(prop.indexOf("Z", prop.length - 1) !== -1) {
                    d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds(), d.getMilliseconds()));                  
                }

            // d is now a local time equivalent to the supplied time
            return d;
        }

        function checkFromXmlDateTimePaths(value, childName, fullPath) {
            if(config.datetimeAccessFormPaths.length > 0) {
                var path = fullPath.split("\.#")[0];
                if(checkInStdFiltersArrayForm(config.datetimeAccessFormPaths, value, childName, path)) {
                    return fromXmlDateTime(value);
                }
                else
                    return value;           
            }
            else
                return value;
        }

        function checkXmlElementsFilter(obj, childType, childName, childPath) {
            if( childType == DOMNodeTypes.ELEMENT_NODE && config.xmlElementsFilter.length > 0) {
                return checkInStdFiltersArrayForm(config.xmlElementsFilter, obj, childName, childPath); 
            }
            else
                return true;
        }   

        function parseDOMChildren( node, path ) {
            if(node.nodeType == DOMNodeTypes.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
                var result = new Object;
                var nodeChildren = node.childNodes;
                // Alternative for firstElementChild which is not supported in some environments
                for(var cidx=0; cidx <nodeChildren.length; cidx++) {
                    var child = nodeChildren.item(cidx);
                    if(child.nodeType == DOMNodeTypes.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        var childName = getNodeLocalName(child);
                        result[childName] = parseDOMChildren(child, childName);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
            else
            if(node.nodeType == DOMNodeTypes.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                var result = new Object;
                result.__cnt=0;

                var nodeChildren = node.childNodes;

                // Children nodes
                for(var cidx=0; cidx <nodeChildren.length; cidx++) {
                    var child = nodeChildren.item(cidx); // nodeChildren[cidx];
                    var childName = getNodeLocalName(child);

                    if(child.nodeType!= DOMNodeTypes.COMMENT_NODE) {
                        var childPath = path+"."+childName;
                        if (checkXmlElementsFilter(result,child.nodeType,childName,childPath)) {
                            result.__cnt++;
                            if(result[childName] == null) {
                                result[childName] = parseDOMChildren(child, childPath);
                                toArrayAccessForm(result, childName, childPath);                    
                            }
                            else {
                                if(result[childName] != null) {
                                    if( !(result[childName] instanceof Array)) {
                                        result[childName] = [result[childName]];
                                        toArrayAccessForm(result, childName, childPath);
                                    }
                                }
                                (result[childName])[result[childName].length] = parseDOMChildren(child, childPath);
                            }
                        }
                    }                               
                }

                // Attributes
                for(var aidx=0; aidx <node.attributes.length; aidx++) {
                    var attr = node.attributes.item(aidx); // [aidx];
                    result.__cnt++;
                    result[config.attributePrefix+attr.name]=attr.value;
                }

                // Node namespace prefix
                var nodePrefix = getNodePrefix(node);
                if(nodePrefix!=null && nodePrefix!="") {
                    result.__cnt++;
                    result.__prefix=nodePrefix;
                }

                if(result["#text"]!=null) {             
                    result.__text = result["#text"];
                    if(result.__text instanceof Array) {
                        result.__text = result.__text.join("\n");
                    }
                    //if(config.escapeMode)
                    //  result.__text = unescapeXmlChars(result.__text);
                    if(config.stripWhitespaces)
                        result.__text = result.__text.trim();
                    delete result["#text"];
                    if(config.arrayAccessForm=="property")
                        delete result["#text_asArray"];
                    result.__text = checkFromXmlDateTimePaths(result.__text, childName, path+"."+childName);
                }
                if(result["#cdata-section"]!=null) {
                    result.__cdata = result["#cdata-section"];
                    delete result["#cdata-section"];
                    if(config.arrayAccessForm=="property")
                        delete result["#cdata-section_asArray"];
                }

                if( result.__cnt == 0 && config.emptyNodeForm=="text" ) {
                    result = '';
                }
                else
                if( result.__cnt == 1 && result.__text!=null  ) {
                    result = result.__text;
                }
                else
                if( result.__cnt == 1 && result.__cdata!=null && !config.keepCData  ) {
                    result = result.__cdata;
                }           
                else            
                if ( result.__cnt > 1 && result.__text!=null && config.skipEmptyTextNodesForObj) {
                    if( (config.stripWhitespaces && result.__text=="") || (result.__text.trim()=="")) {
                        delete result.__text;
                    }
                }
                delete result.__cnt;            

                if( config.enableToStringFunc && (result.__text!=null || result.__cdata!=null )) {
                    result.toString = function() {
                        return (this.__text!=null? this.__text:'')+( this.__cdata!=null ? this.__cdata:'');
                    };
                }

                return result;
            }
            else
            if(node.nodeType == DOMNodeTypes.TEXT_NODE || node.nodeType == DOMNodeTypes.CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
                return node.nodeValue;
            }   
        }

        function startTag(jsonObj, element, attrList, closed) {
            var resultStr = "<"+ ( (jsonObj!=null && jsonObj.__prefix!=null)? (jsonObj.__prefix+":"):"") + element;
            if(attrList!=null) {
                for(var aidx = 0; aidx < attrList.length; aidx++) {
                    var attrName = attrList[aidx];
                    var attrVal = jsonObj[attrName];
                    if(config.escapeMode)
                        attrVal=escapeXmlChars(attrVal);
                    resultStr+=" "+attrName.substr(config.attributePrefix.length)+"=";
                    if(config.useDoubleQuotes)
                        resultStr+='"'+attrVal+'"';
                    else
                        resultStr+="'"+attrVal+"'";
                }
            }
            if(!closed)
                resultStr+=">";
            else
                resultStr+="/>";
            return resultStr;
        }

        function endTag(jsonObj,elementName) {
            return "</"+ (jsonObj.__prefix!=null? (jsonObj.__prefix+":"):"")+elementName+">";
        }

        function endsWith(str, suffix) {
            return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
        }

        function jsonXmlSpecialElem ( jsonObj, jsonObjField ) {
            if((config.arrayAccessForm=="property" && endsWith(jsonObjField.toString(),("_asArray"))) 
                    || jsonObjField.toString().indexOf(config.attributePrefix)==0 
                    || jsonObjField.toString().indexOf("__")==0
                    || (jsonObj[jsonObjField] instanceof Function) )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        function jsonXmlElemCount ( jsonObj ) {
            var elementsCnt = 0;
            if(jsonObj instanceof Object ) {
                for( var it in jsonObj  ) {
                    if(jsonXmlSpecialElem ( jsonObj, it) )
                        continue;           
                    elementsCnt++;
                }
            }
            return elementsCnt;
        }

        function checkJsonObjPropertiesFilter(jsonObj, propertyName, jsonObjPath) {
            return config.jsonPropertiesFilter.length == 0
                || jsonObjPath==""
                || checkInStdFiltersArrayForm(config.jsonPropertiesFilter, jsonObj, propertyName, jsonObjPath); 
        }

        function parseJSONAttributes ( jsonObj ) {
            var attrList = [];
            if(jsonObj instanceof Object ) {
                for( var ait in jsonObj  ) {
                    if(ait.toString().indexOf("__")== -1 && ait.toString().indexOf(config.attributePrefix)==0) {
                        attrList.push(ait);
                    }
                }
            }
            return attrList;
        }

        function parseJSONTextAttrs ( jsonTxtObj ) {
            var result ="";

            if(jsonTxtObj.__cdata!=null) {                                      
                result+="<![CDATA["+jsonTxtObj.__cdata+"]]>";                   
            }

            if(jsonTxtObj.__text!=null) {           
                if(config.escapeMode)
                    result+=escapeXmlChars(jsonTxtObj.__text);
                else
                    result+=jsonTxtObj.__text;
            }
            return result;
        }

        function parseJSONTextObject ( jsonTxtObj ) {
            var result ="";

            if( jsonTxtObj instanceof Object ) {
                result+=parseJSONTextAttrs ( jsonTxtObj );
            }
            else
                if(jsonTxtObj!=null) {
                    if(config.escapeMode)
                        result+=escapeXmlChars(jsonTxtObj);
                    else
                        result+=jsonTxtObj;
                }

            return result;
        }

        function getJsonPropertyPath(jsonObjPath, jsonPropName) {
            if (jsonObjPath==="") {
                return jsonPropName;
            }
            else
                return jsonObjPath+"."+jsonPropName;
        }

        function parseJSONArray ( jsonArrRoot, jsonArrObj, attrList, jsonObjPath ) {
            var result = ""; 
            if(jsonArrRoot.length == 0) {
                result+=startTag(jsonArrRoot, jsonArrObj, attrList, true);
            }
            else {
                for(var arIdx = 0; arIdx < jsonArrRoot.length; arIdx++) {
                    result+=startTag(jsonArrRoot[arIdx], jsonArrObj, parseJSONAttributes(jsonArrRoot[arIdx]), false);
                    result+=parseJSONObject(jsonArrRoot[arIdx], getJsonPropertyPath(jsonObjPath,jsonArrObj));
                    result+=endTag(jsonArrRoot[arIdx],jsonArrObj);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        function parseJSONObject ( jsonObj, jsonObjPath ) {
            var result = "";    

            var elementsCnt = jsonXmlElemCount ( jsonObj );

            if(elementsCnt > 0) {
                for( var it in jsonObj ) {

                    if(jsonXmlSpecialElem ( jsonObj, it) || (jsonObjPath!="" && !checkJsonObjPropertiesFilter(jsonObj, it, getJsonPropertyPath(jsonObjPath,it))) )
                        continue;           

                    var subObj = jsonObj[it];                       

                    var attrList = parseJSONAttributes( subObj )

                    if(subObj == null || subObj == undefined) {
                        result+=startTag(subObj, it, attrList, true);
                    }
                    else
                    if(subObj instanceof Object) {

                        if(subObj instanceof Array) {                   
                            result+=parseJSONArray( subObj, it, attrList, jsonObjPath );                    
                        }
                        else if(subObj instanceof Date) {
                            result+=startTag(subObj, it, attrList, false);
                            result+=subObj.toISOString();
                            result+=endTag(subObj,it);
                        }
                        else {
                            var subObjElementsCnt = jsonXmlElemCount ( subObj );
                            if(subObjElementsCnt > 0 || subObj.__text!=null || subObj.__cdata!=null) {
                                result+=startTag(subObj, it, attrList, false);
                                result+=parseJSONObject(subObj, getJsonPropertyPath(jsonObjPath,it));
                                result+=endTag(subObj,it);
                            }
                            else {
                                result+=startTag(subObj, it, attrList, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        result+=startTag(subObj, it, attrList, false);
                        result+=parseJSONTextObject(subObj);
                        result+=endTag(subObj,it);
                    }
                }
            }
            result+=parseJSONTextObject(jsonObj);

            return result;
        }

        this.parseXmlString = function(xmlDocStr) {
            var isIEParser = window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window;
            if (xmlDocStr === undefined) {
                return null;
            }
            var xmlDoc;
            if (window.DOMParser) {
                var parser=new window.DOMParser();          
                var parsererrorNS = null;
                // IE9+ now is here
                if(!isIEParser) {
                    try {
                        parsererrorNS = parser.parseFromString("INVALID", "text/xml").getElementsByTagName("parsererror")[0].namespaceURI;
                    }
                    catch(err) {                    
                        parsererrorNS = null;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString( xmlDocStr, "text/xml" );
                    if( parsererrorNS!= null && xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS(parsererrorNS, "parsererror").length > 0) {
                        //throw new Error('Error parsing XML: '+xmlDocStr);
                        xmlDoc = null;
                    }
                }
                catch(err) {
                    xmlDoc = null;
                }
            }
            else {
                // IE :(
                if(xmlDocStr.indexOf("<?")==0) {
                    xmlDocStr = xmlDocStr.substr( xmlDocStr.indexOf("?>") + 2 );
                }
                xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async="false";
                xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlDocStr);
            }
            return xmlDoc;
        };

        this.asArray = function(prop) {
            if (prop === undefined || prop == null)
                return [];
            else
            if(prop instanceof Array)
                return prop;
            else
                return [prop];
        };

        this.toXmlDateTime = function(dt) {
            if(dt instanceof Date)
                return dt.toISOString();
            else
            if(typeof(dt) === 'number' )
                return new Date(dt).toISOString();
            else    
                return null;
        };

        this.asDateTime = function(prop) {
            if(typeof(prop) == "string") {
                return fromXmlDateTime(prop);
            }
            else
                return prop;
        };

        this.xml2json = function (xmlDoc) {
            return parseDOMChildren ( xmlDoc );
        };

        this.xml_str2json = function (xmlDocStr) {
            var xmlDoc = this.parseXmlString(xmlDocStr);
            if(xmlDoc!=null)
                return this.xml2json(xmlDoc);
            else
                return null;
        };

        this.json2xml_str = function (jsonObj) {
            return parseJSONObject ( jsonObj, "" );
        };

        this.json2xml = function (jsonObj) {
            var xmlDocStr = this.json2xml_str (jsonObj);
            return this.parseXmlString(xmlDocStr);
        };

        this.getVersion = function () {
            return VERSION;
        };  
    }
}))

// Create x2js instance with default config
var x2js = new X2JS();
var xmlText = "";

jQuery.getJSON( "https://service1.homepro.com/smart.asmx/GetFAP_ProfileReviewsJSON?bid=141772&sort=1&page=1", function( data ) {
    var xmlText = data,
    x2js = new X2JS(),
    jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json( xmlText ),
    html = '<div class="flex-wrapper">';
    // console.log(jsonObj.SMART);  

    jQuery.each( jsonObj.SMART.XMLJSON, function( key, answer ) {
        html += '<div class="flex-shell testimonial">';
        html += '<div class="flex-item">';
        html += '<div>';
        html += '<span class="review-number"><i>' + answer.Quality + '</i> Quality of work</span>' ;
        html += '<span class="review-number"><i>' + answer.Time + '</i> Timeliness</span>' ;
        html += '<span class="review-number"><i>' + answer.Budget + '</i> Value for Money</span>' ;
        html += '<span class="review-number"><i>' + answer.Courtesy + '</i> Courtesy</span>' ;
        html += '<span class="review">' + answer.Testimonial + '</span>' ;
        html += '<span class="name">' + answer.RefName + ' - ' + answer.refDate + '</span>';                            
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
    });

    jQuery('.start').html(html);
});

//above here
});
```

Apologies if I've gone about this in the wrong way. I've done;

> npm install xml2json

Which didn't flag up any errors but I still can't seem to get the data to load correctly.

Comment: Hi! You're likely to get better answers if you can provide a [mcve] - there's a lot of code for people to read through here, and most of it is probably not needed to demonstrate your problem. Try to come up with a smaller program that still leads to the same error.

Comment: please try `var x2js = new window.X2JS();`

Comment: @huynhsamha thanks for the comment and trying to help, I tired what you suggested and no difference sadly.

Comment: @Sam what package you are using? Is it https://www.npmjs.com/package/x2js?

Comment: @Sam I've given you an answer to your problem. Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution that after you import `<script>` from package `x2js`, you should use `window.X2JS` to get constructor of `X2JS`. Almost packages implementing for both NPM and browser, the browser version usually use via object `window`, because it is shared and free connected in almost browsers.

This is my demo for the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/2evdgt7r/

In my demo, I've include package `x2js` from NPM here https://unpkg.com/x2js@3.2.3/x2js.js

```
var X2JS = window.X2JS;

var x2js = new X2JS();

const data = {
  a: {
    b: 1
  },
  c: [1, 2]
}

console.log(x2js.js2xml(data))
// <a><b>1</b></a><c>1</c><c>2</c>
```